# Did Hitler ever make this quote?

Tags: quotes, adolf-hitler

Found this one [floating around going viral](https://www.facebook.com/RevolutionaryMemesExtreme/photos/a.1029237850456132.1073741826.1029234067123177/1297089970337584/?type=3&permPage=1). Has the moment that Richard Spencer was punched in the face, followed by this quote.

> "Only one thing could have stopped our movement - if our adversaries had understood its principle and from the first day smashed with the utmost brutality the nucleus of our new movement." - Adolph Hitler

[image: Hitler Quote]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a loose translation of something that he said according to a [researcher](https://zuriz.wordpress.com/2013/10/06/smashing-the-nucleus/). In [*Die Reden Hitlers am Reichsparteitag 1933*](http://archive.org/stream/Die-Reden-Hitlers-am-Reichsparteitag-1933/DieRedenHitlersAmReichsparteitag1933193427Doppels.ScanFraktur#page/n21/mode/1up), a compilation of speeches given by Hitler, he said this.

> Eine einzige Gefahr konnte es gegen diese Entwicklung geben: Wenn der
>   Gegner das Prinzip erkannte, Klarheit über diese Gedanken erhielt und
>   jeden Widerstand vermied. Oder wenn er mit letzter Brutalität am
>   ersten Tag den ersten Keim der neuen Sammlung vernichtete.

> **Only one danger could have jeopardised this development – if our
>   adversaries had understood its principle,** established a clear
>   understanding of our ideas, and not offered any resistance. Or,
>   alternatively, if they had **from the first day annihilated with the
>   utmost brutality the nucleus of our new movement.**

Comment: I added the original german from your link. The translation seems reasonably accurate in my opinion.I didn't verify the source of the document you linked.

Comment: I don't think it's the best translation, but the differences are small and do not change the overall meaning of the passage.  For example, the first sentence says more simply that "there could be" only one danger; there's no verb meaning "jeopardized."  The German speaks of "avoiding" resistance, which is more active than "not offering" it.  And "nucleus" may not be the best translation for "Keim."  But the translation does convey the point of the original.

Comment: which would be entirely in character, seeing as Hitler had experienced just such action on the part of the Bavarian authorities after the Beerhall putch attempt, the failure that landed him in prison to write Mein Kampf.

Comment: I feel like there's a lot of context behind this.